# Does spring cloud contract supports Soap-Web-Services?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to use spring-cloud-contract in Soap-web-services.

UC:- I have one soap-consumer application and I want to connect to downstream which I don't have access to. For now, I am using wire mock as a stub. I want to implement spring-cloud-contract for contract testing.

For that, I couldn't found any examples of soap-web-services. Does spring-cloud-contract supports soap-services. If yes, Can I get some guidance on how to do the same? or any link which helps. I have to implement it in a single application(consumer application).

Comment: Hope this will be helpful https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ if you havn't check already

Comment: Hi, @OEH Thanks for the response. I am looking for spring-cloud-contract implementation in soap-web-services. Mainly on the consumer side as I don't have access or can't do any changes to downstream(producers)